# Delete content of parent folder, except subsubfolder

Tags: batch-file

For example, I have

```
PATH\ParentFolder\SubFolder1\SubSubFolder11
PATH\ParentFolder\SubFolder1\SubSubFolder12
PATH\ParentFolder\SubFolder2\SubSubFolder21
```

I need to delete all except `SubSubFolder11`.

I think the best way is to make a loop and delete each folder except `SubSubFolder11`. Or mark a folder as hidden?

(I'm new in batch)

Comment: You can simply move the subfolder to another location and delete the rest.

Comment: No. Except of this. Before my question, I used such solution, but problem appear when no have free space on disc, and System trying to copy big amount of data.

Comment: In that case, you can delete the rest first and `move` later.

Comment: This folder is bigger than other in thousand's times, does't matter.

Comment: What about the content of `SubFolder11`? do you want to keep it? May there be multiple folders named `SubFolder11`? And what about `SubFolder2`? should it be removed also? Anyway, you have an idea how to do it, so why don't you just try it?

Comment: @aschipfl: All folders with content should be deleted, except 'SubSubFolder11'. Just skip this folder during deleting

Comment: @DimaGrigoriev: Can you try it with `move`? AFAIK, it doesn't literally `move` every byte in the memory rather what is does is just update the directory entries in the filesystem. To do this by `copy`ing obviously won't be a good solution.

Comment: @Azeem i will try, but not looks good.

Comment: What your question asks, **Delete parent folder except subsubfolder**, cannot be done, `ParentFolder` can never be deleted because it is a container for your exception `SubSubFolder11`. Could you please use your opening question's **edit** facility to both clarify your question and post the code you are having difficulties with.

Comment: @Compo okay. "Delete content of parent folder, except subsubfolder"

Comment: Could you please use your opening question's **edit** facility to both clarify your question and post the code you are having difficulties with.

Comment: Your description is wrong. Both sub-sub-folder `SubSubFolder11` _and_ sub-folder `SubFolder1` should not be deleted...

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet walks through the entire directory tree beginning at deeper hierarchy levels and deletes files and directories if the current path does not contain element `SubFolder11`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=PATH"
set "_EXCEPT=SubFolder11"

rem // Iterate over directory tree from deep to shallow levels:
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
    dir /S /B /A:D "%_ROOT%\*" ^| sort /R
') do (
    rem // Store current directory path with `\` appended:
    set "PDIR=%%~D\"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check whether path contains dir. name to exclude:
    if /I "!PDIR:\%_EXCEPT%\=!"=="!PDIR!" (
        rem // Dir. name not found, so delete files:
        del /Q "!PDIR!*.*"
        rem // Delete empty sub-directories:
        rd "!PDIR!." 2> nul
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```